# Java Memory Model: reordering and concurrent locks

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, synchronized

The java meomry model mandates that `synchronize` blocks that synchronize on the same monitor enforce a before-after-realtion on the variables modified within those blocks. Example:

```
// in thread A
synchronized( lock )
{
  x = true;
}

// in thread B
synchronized( lock )
{
  System.out.println( x );
}
```

In this case it is garanteed that thread B will see `x==true` as long as thread A already passed that `synchronized`-block. Now I am in the process to rewrite lots of code to use the more flexible (and said to be faster) locks in `java.util.concurrent`, especially the `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. So the example looks like this:

*EDIT*: The example was broken, because I incorrectly transformed the code, as noted by *matt b*. Fixed as follows:

```
// in thread A
lock.writeLock().lock();
{
  x = true;
}
lock.writeLock().unlock();

// in thread B
lock.readLock().lock();
{
  System.out.println( x );
}
lock.readLock().unlock();
```

However, I have not seen any hints within the memory model specification that such locks also imply the nessessary ordering. Looking into the implementation it seems to rely on the access to volatile variables inside `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` (for the sun implementation at least). However this is not part of any specification and moreover access to non-volatile variables is not really condsidered covered by the memory barrier given by these variables, is it?

So, here are my questions:

- Is it safe to assume the same ordering as with the "old" `synchronized` blocks?
- Is this documented somewhere?
- Is accessing any volatile variable a memory barrier for any other variable?

Regards,
  Steffen

--

Comment to Yanamon:

Look at the following code:

```
// in thread a
x = 1;
synchronized ( a ) { y = 2; }
z = 3;

// in thread b
System.out.println( x );
synchronized ( a ) { System.out.println( y ); }
System.out.println( z );
```

From what I understood, the memory barrier enforces the second output to show 2, but has no guaranteed affect on the other variables...? So how can this be compared to accessing a volatile variable?

Comment: One note about the code you added, thread b will only print 2 if it gets the lock for a before thread a... that was kind of implied but I just wanted to make that clear.

But to answer you volatile question, volatile be used in the following manner to enforce visibility:
--------
volatile boolean memoryBarrier = false;
int unguardedValue = 0;

//thread a:
unguardedValue = 10;
memoryBarrier = true;

// thread b
if (memoryBarrier) {
  // unguardedValue is guaranteed to be read as 10;
}

Comment: Well I guess writing code in comments doesn't really work well, I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [API-doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> All Lock implementations must enforce
>   the same memory synchronization
>   semantics as provided by the built-in
>   monitor lock, as described in  The
>   Java Language Specification, Third
>   Edition (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> ```
> * A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Lock action.
> * A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Unlock action.
> ```
>
> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking
>   operations, and reentrant
>   locking/unlocking operations, do not
>   require any memory synchronization
>   effects.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've read a lot of things, but I seem to have completely missed the Lock interface itself....

Comment: Can you comment on the volatile question?

Comment: @Steffen Heil: If I recall it correctly, any access to a volatile variable has only synchronizing effect with other accesses to the same variable, i.e., is not guaranteed to provide some kind of general memory barrier. A quick scan of the JLS seems to confirm this recollection. But take this with a huge grain of salt, as it has been quite some time since I last had a closer encounter with the memory model and its implications...

Comment: Check out http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#64058 for the explanation of how reading and writing a volatile enforce synchronization order which is more of a general memory barrier than just up to date read/write of just the volatile variable.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond the question of what the semantics of the memory model guarantees, I think there are a few problems with the code you are posting.

1. You are synchronizing *twice* on the same lock - this is unnecessary. When using a `Lock` implementation, you don't have need to use the `synchronized` block.
2. The standard idiom for using a `Lock` is to do so in a try-finally block to prevent accidental unlocking of the lock (since the lock is not automatically released when entering whatever block you are in, as with the `synchronized` block).

You should be using a `Lock` with something resembling:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    //do stuff
}
finally { 
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: You are right, my example was broken. I fixed the question.
And yes, I am usually using try/finally, just leaving it out here for shortness.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing volatile variables now enforces happens before and happens after operation ordering.  Writing to a volatile variable has the same effect as releasing a monitor and reading a variable has the effect as acquiring a monitor.  The following example makes it a little more clear:

```
volatile boolean memoryBarrier = false;
int unguardedValue = 0;

//thread a:
unguardedValue = 10;
memoryBarrier = true;

// thread b
if (memoryBarrier) {
  // unguardedValue is guaranteed to be read as 10;
}
```

---

But that all being said the sample code you provided did not look like it was really using the [`ReentrantLock`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) as it was designed to be used.

1. Surrounding the use of a `Lock` with the the Java's built in `syncronized` keyword effectively makes access to the lock already single threaded so it doesn't give the `Lock` a chance to do any real work.
2. Acquiring a releasing a `Lock` should be done following the pattern below, this is outlined in the java docs of [`Lock`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

---

```
lock.readLock().lock();
try {
  // Do work
} finally {
  lock.readLock.unlock();
}
```

---

Comment: See comment in question, please.

Comment: I understand that thread b won't see unguardedValue because ordering does not affect visibility and unguardedValue is not volatile, thus, not necesarily visible by thread b. Is this right ?

Answer (score 1):

Yanamon, I am not sure you are correct - but for different reasons than the argument you are making.

The unguardedVariable variable may be re-ordered in thread "a" such that its value is set to 10 *after* memoryBarrier is set to true.

"There is no guarantee that operations in one thread will be performed in the order given by the program, as long as the reordering is not detectable within *that* thread - *even if the reordering is apparent to other threads*"

Java Concurrency in Practise, Brian Goetz, p34

UPDATED: what I said is true in the case of the old memory model. So, if you want write-once-run-anywhere then my argument stands. However, in the new memory model, it is not the case as the semantics surrounding re-ordering of non-volatile variables in the presence of volatile access has become stricter (see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile).